# default parameters and inheritance in python

Tags: python, inheritance

Parameter `x1` is given a default value in `ParentClass` and is inherited in `SubClass`.

Is this the cleanest way to initialize `x1` in `SubClass`?  Specifically, I have  assigned value `inaccessible value` and `sub value` to `x1` in `SubClass`, and only `sub value` is accessible.   Wondering if I missed a more canonical way to do this.

```
class ParentClass(object):
def __init__(self, x1='parent value'):
    self.x1 = x1

class SubClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, x1='inaccessible value', x2='sub value'):
        super().__init__(x1='sub value')
        self.x2 = x2
```

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example, with some context about the problem you're solving? If you want the child to have a different default, why not simply `x1='sub value'` then `super().__init__(x1)`? What's the point of `'inaccessible value'`? Using the fixed argument to the parent just prevents the user from actually setting `x1`, breaking the inheritance.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think that's the solution I'm looking for!  Somehow got on the wrong trail.  Is there any difference between your solution and the code in the question?